# Isekai Manga with a blue moon destroyed

Tags: story-identification, moon, isekai

I am trying to find a manga (I'm fairly sure it an isekai) where the main character wants to test out his magic so he tries to shoot down a dragon that is far away. He shoots off his magic and ends up destroying one of the planets blue moon.

Addendum: there is a second moon that is, I think red, that comes out unscathed. Also this manga might be a harem type. the MC is not a child, though he may be reincarnated and grows up, I can't remember. He meets a female knight that comes to investigate if demons or the demon lord had something to do with the destroyed moon. I don't think he is a demon lord but maybe I don't remember.

Comment: Can you remember anything else about this? When did you read it? How did he get his magic? What magic was it? What were the consequences? Etc. If you have anything else to add that you remember you can [edit] your question.

Comment: You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for [Saikyou no Shuzoku ga Ningen Datta Ken](https://mangadex.org/title/29735/saikyou-no-shuzoku-ga-ningen-datta-ken).

Specifically, the scene you are looking for is in chapter 5.  The main character fires off magic towards a dragon, and the blue moon disappears. Chapter 10 has the main character meeting a female knight who was looking for the elf that was traveling with the main character. She mentions that everyone is in an uproar because the moon was destroyed.

As a warning, the manga contains nudity and sexual situations.